# Could the Android App be made available via Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I own a Amazon Kindle Fire tablet, and was slightly disappointed not to see the [Stack Exchange Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) available on the [Amazon Appstore](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dmobile-apps&field-keywords=Stack%20Exchange), although there are some third-party apps available:

[image]

My original request was going to be this:

> Could the Stack Exchange Android app be made available on the Amazon Appstore?

However as I thought this, it **could start to get tricky maintaining the app** (e.g, for each new version, submission to three appstores & two different platforms), and I'm uncomfortable sideloading or using the third-party apps available:

- I don't want to risk my data being sent off to some hidden server, to be mined (*especially my username & password*);
- The designs of thirty-party apps aren't... in the spirit of Stack Exchange;
- **Sideloading would mean I would have to download the app from a third-party, which may have infected it with malware/naughty things**

*Despite being relatively low-rep, I have worked hard for my reputation and have no intention to lose it (so please don't say "you're low-rep, it wouldn't matter if your account got stolen").*

This leads me to ask this: **Could the Stack Exchange Android App be made available via the Stack Exchange website?**